# Put an IV fluid up

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Back where I come from, we would usually say 'I started the patient on a drip'. But for the 'word' *put up* ... I only find it natural to say 'I put the fluid up just an hour ago'. What would happen if I were to include a patient in my sentence:

'I put the fluid up (in/on/for) the patient just an hour ago.'

Are all of the options unusual?

Comment: I'd not use 'for the patient' (and definitely not the other two suggestions) after 'I put the fluid up' in a sentence. You could use a vocative: 'Mrs Tankerey?  I put the fluid up just an hour ago.' But I far prefer your 'I started ...' alternative.

Comment: Maybe it should be *put the **patient** on the fluid*. The *for* version seems fine (it's done on behalf of the patient, to benefit the patient, or perhaps at the patient's request). The other 2 alternatives (and the null alternative) are all grammatically sound, if not medically. I echo @Edwin's preference for the *on a drip* version.

Comment: Is it grammatically correct to say this though... I used this once and it sounded okay to me. but then again English is my third language. "I'll go check it with you after putting this fluid up for my patient".

Comment: On the TV medical shows I've generally heard "hang", as in "hang another bag of saline".

Comment: we do use hang as well sometimes. However my question would be what comes next if i put 'the patient' in the sentence. Hang another bag of saline for/in/on/to... though I usually opt for for.

Comment: @RafaelM “Hang another bag of saline in the patient” sounds not only wrong, but like something quite likely to lead to a dead patient, lots of gore, and probably also some kind of disciplinary hearing and/or criminal charges. Would definitely avoid.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hang+another+bag+of+saline%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @HotLicks It's not the act of hanging the bag that sounds dangerous, but the act of hanging it ***inside the patient***. You'd normally hang the bag outside the patient’s body.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I know it sounds awful. That's whyI'm asking what's the best preposition to use as I find it just as wrong as you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do for a living.  Never heard "I put up an IV bag."  All over the USA, it's mostly "I hung the fluid about an hour ago" or "I'm about to hang it" but if it is a specific drip, we say "drip" instead of fluid.  Same with antibiotics.  "What time did you hang it?"

Comment: Put up is quite commonly used in the UK. But for now let's use the word hang. if you were to put "the patient" in the sentence, what preposition would you use? would you say Could you hang this bag of fluid in/on/for/to the patient? Thanks.